# available modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Q:

I want to list the most used modal pop up in asp.net to select the convenient one to my case, i used Ajax modal pop up before but i don't like it,i want the modal pop either it was an extender or jquery or what ever allow me to access the .cs (server side)..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ ?

Comment: You mean you want to open Modal Popup(Dialog) Server Side ? After a postback ?

Comment: no i mean accessing the server controls on the the modal pop up

Comment: what do you mean ? needs more information , modal pop up is a DIV or other containers so you can put every server side controls in them

Comment: good that what i mean , access the server side controls events.

Comment: http://www.mbmt.net/JQ/JQDialogTest.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Execute every javascript/jQuery Code Serverside 
You could use the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) method from the code behind:

```
public void SomeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "$('#someid').dialog('open');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", script, true);
}
```

you may use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) Or [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and other available Plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery model dialog is best.You can easily integrate this with asp.net.

Check out the following link for how to integrate Jquery model dialog in asp.net

[How to use jquery dialog in asp.net](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-jquery-dialog-in-aspnet.html)